# Drupal: setting up a svn

Tags: svn, drupal, drupal-6

I'm setting up for the first time SVN for my Drupal website. (It is not connected to the Drupal repository but to synch the remote and local versions of my websites with a 3rd party SVN hosting service)

The question is simple:  I would prefer to not complicate too much the server path to my website..

> i.e.
>   /var/www/repository_name/trunk/mywebsite/

is a bit too long.. I would prefer to keep it simple as it is now:

> /var/www/mywebsite

Should I maybe use symbolic links ? What's the professional way to setup SVN ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /var/www
svn co http://server/repository_name/trunk/mywebsite
```

or

```
cd /var/www
svn co http://server/repository_name/trunk/mywebsites_name_in_repo mywebsite
```

Answer (score 3):

The website is not served directly from the repository. The website is served from either a working copy or an exported copy of the repository. Furthermore, the repository is not accessed directly, but only by means of an SVN client. A wokring copy always knows from which repository it as taken. In light of that, there is no need to keep the path to the repository short.

Comment: All right thanks. I've actually thought the working copy have the same directory structure of the repository (i.e. trunk/) but I now see it is not true. Only the original files indeed.